# Ubuntu Boot Error:Kernel Image not found

Tags: installation, boot

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail) from my FAT formatted USB installed with unetbooting and I got the error

> No kernel Image found:

I ran md5sums on the ISO image, and it tallies but error persists.
I formatted the USB drive to FAT32 but I got the error

> No UI Directive or config file found

Any tips on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need unetbootin any longer. You can write the ISO directly to USB using [dd for Windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd)

Remove all USB drives that you have installed except the one you want to install the Ubuntu ISO to before running the below command to avoid the possibility of overwriting other drives.

You would want to use a command like this (IT WILL ERASE YOUR USB DRIVE, BACK UP ANYTHING YOU WANT TO KEEP FIRST):

```
dd.exe --filter=removable if=C:\path\to\ubuntu.iso of=\\?\\Device\\Harddisk1\\Partition0
```

The exact directive you need the Harddisk portion of of= is highly dependant on your computer configuration. If you want to see the list of devices, use `dd.exe --list`. You'll want to look for an entry that has "Removable media other than floppy. Block size = 512". You always want to use Partition0 though. Also, be sure you keep the --filter=removable part of the command to avoid overwriting your internal hard drives.